# FPTAS algorithm to find flow at each link for multi commodity flow problem?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, np-complete, approximation, network-flow

Given a graph $G$ and $K$ commodities to route from source to destination. I want to find, what is the maximum beneficial flow for each of the commodities and the relevant paths. I understand the problem in general falls under NPC, hence I am looking for FPTAS algorithms.

I am struggling with the problem, so any intuitive idea to tackle the problem is also most welcome.

Comment: What research have you done?  The wikipedia page for multi-commodity flow claims to have a reference to a FPTAS for the problem, if fractional flows are allowed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-commodity_flow_problem.  You don't specify whether you're OK with fractional flows.  If not, you could try applying randomized rounding.